# How do I preload cache on litespeed?

Tags: wordpress, caching, litespeed

I have a website running on LiteSpeed server and I need to clear cache every hour of the homepage since its dynamic. The home page takes a very long time to load when it is not cached.

I tried using -wget on cron jobs but for some reason it doesn't work when I'm using LiteSpeed cache plugin, but when I use other plugins like WP Fastest Cache it works fine.

Is there anyway I can preload the page to create the cache?

[pacotes de viagem baratos](https://www.pacotebarato.com.br)

Comment: if you are using plugin , doesn't plugin have crawler to pre-cache the site ?   why don't you use that ?

Comment: the crawler on the plugin is too complex i don't really know how it works D:

Comment: Docs is here https://docs.litespeedtech.com/lscache/lscwp/crawler/, hope it helps. If you don't mind to share the link, I can also try to find out the wet/curl command for you.

Comment: Hi Eric, the links is www.pacotebarato.com.br

Comment: I have switched to WProcker and they have  a prebuilt function that works just fine, plus cloudflare made my webiste way faster too. [Jericoacoara, onde fica, como ir, e o que fazer de dia e de noite em 2021](https://pacotebarato.com.br/artigo-de-viagem/jericoacoara-onde-fica-como-ir-e-o-que-fazer-dia-e-noite/)